# how to remove jquery filter from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

I have a function that I want to remove jQuery from:

```
var hunt = new RegExp(action.search);
$('a').filter(function() {
  return hunt.test(this.href);
}).click(doStuff);
```

I am trying to rewrite this function using vanilla javascript. this is what I have so far but it is not working

```
    var hunt = new RegExp(action.search);
    var aSelector = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var arr = Array.prototype.filter.call(aSelector, function(el){
        return hunt.test(el.href)
    });
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        var elem = arr[i].getAttribute('href');
        elem.onclick = function(){
            doStuff();
        };
    }
```

I am guessing that the jQuery selector behavior is slightly different than document.getElementsByTagName but I really have no idea what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: var elem = arr[i].getAttribute('href'); gets the 'href' attribute value for each element. You then try to assign a click handler to the returned value.

Comment: Rule# 1: simply saying something "is not working" is not a good way to write a question. Is there an error? What is the expected vs. actual behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better use `querySelectorAll()` instead of `getElementsByTagName()`, besides that, I think the code is self-explaining. Ask if something is unclear

```
//a very basic utility to fetch Nodes by css-selectors and return them as an Array
//- shorthand for document.querySelectorAll()
//- document.querySelectorAll() returns a NodeList wich lacks the Array-methods
//- second argument to provide a Node as the context of the query
function $$(selector, context){
    return Array.from((typeof context === "object" && context || document).querySelectorAll(selector));
}

//now we can use the regular Array-methods
$$('a').filter(function(node){
    return hunt.test(node.href);
}).forEach(function(node){
    node.addEventListener("click", doStuff);
})
```

or this way:

```
$$('a').forEach(function(node){
    if(hunt.test(node.href)){
        node.addEventListener("click", doStuff);
    }
});
```